# IP not getting released from interface - Redhat 7

Tags: ssh, interface

I am trying to use a single IP as a "floating IP" by assigning it to a secondary interface eth1 between 2 VMs. The primary interface eth0 has 2 different IPs for both VMs. Only one of the VMs will have the IP assigned to eth1 at any given time. If we have any issues with the primary VM we will unassign the IP from eth1 of the primary VM and reassign it to the secondary VM.

We are unassigning and assigning the IP using -

/sbin/ip addr ${ACTION} ${IP} dev ${INTERFACE}

However once we unassign the IP from eth1 of the primary VM and assign it to eth1 of the secondary VM I am unable to ssh to the secondary VM right away. I get a -

ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection timed out

After about 15 mins some cache somewhere gets cleared and then I am able to ssh to the secondary box.

Have the following setting already updated in sshd_config and sshd has been restarted.

GSSAPIAuthentication no
UseDNS no

We are using Redhat 7.6

Any help in the troubleshooting what could be causing the delay in ssh'ing to the secondary box is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with your network gear and the clients arp tables.

After you change the address check your arp tables with arp -a on Linux and show ip arp (Cisco gear). You will see the old MAC address maps to the old server IP.

After you change ip addresses send a gratuitous arp and that will force everything to update.

Assume your ethernet address is 10.0.10.1 and you are using eth1.

```
yum install arping -y
arping -A -I eth1 10.0.10.1
```

This very similar to what VMware does when you VMotion a VM to another host. It sends an RARP to notify the network the MAC address has moved to different a port.

EDIT: Also note, in older RHEL ver ifup-eth script used the arping tool to send a GARP. That means I might also try ip link set eth1 down and ip link set eth1 up see if that works.

Comment: Thank you so much superbovine.  I tried the arping -A -I eth1 x.x.x.x command but still no luck. However the weird part is when I assign the IP and do an arp -a I see that the floating IP is assigned to eth0 and not eth1. Not sure if that is right. Definitely looks like some kind of arp caching maybe on the switch above the VM cluster.

Comment: Are you sure you are not assigning a duplicate ip?

Comment: Yup we checked that and its not a duplicate. Also after 10 mins the same IP on eth1 starts working and we are able to ssh. It just doesnt start functioning rightaway.

Comment: Walked me through all the steps you use to unconfig the nic and reconfigure the nic on the other VM.

Comment: To unassign the IP we use - ip addr del x.x.x.x dev eth1 and to assign the IP we use ip addr add x.x.x.x dev eth1. eth1 has its own config file on each of the boxes.

Comment: When you say you see the floating ip on eth0, how do you see it ? ip addr?

Are you using any type of bonding?

Comment: Sorry was out  for a couple of days. We are not using bonding. I am doing an `arp -n` on the box and see the IP assigned to eth0 as incomplete

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved. We had to update the arp neihbor cache to get this to work so incorporated that into our script.